# Why do I have to call `sum` twice to sum a list of `Maybe Integer`s?

Tags: haskell, sum, option-type

I wrote a solution for a very simple practice problem:

> Calculate the number of grains of wheat on a chessboard given that the number on each square doubles. Write code that shows how many grains are on a given square, and the total number of grains on the chessboard.

The function must return a `Maybe Integer` and return `Nothing` if the input is less than 1 or greater than 64.

```
square :: Integer -> Maybe Integer
square n = if (n < 1 || n > 64) then Nothing else Just (2^(pred n))
total :: Integer
total = sum (fmap sum (map square [1..64]))
```

I tried to apply `fmap sum` to some test output of `map square` (list of `Maybe Integer`) in GHCI and was surprised to discover it returns the list of integers (sans `Just`) rather than their sum. So in the solution above I apply `sum` a second time to actually get the sum.

I would like to understand conceptually why this is the case: in other words why is `sum` behaving like a converter for Maybe Ints to Ints in this context instead of adding things?

I've solved some similar exercises relying on helper functions to avoid complications of doing computation on `Maybe` values, and perhaps in this case I should just calculate the value of `total` without utilizing `square`, i.e.:

```
total = sum [2^n | n <- [0..63]]
```

However since I'd already written a useful function my first instinct was to reuse it, which led to some unforeseen behavior.

Comment: You can code your expression for total a bit more elegantly, as fmap has the property that (fmap fn1) . (fmap fn2) is equivalent to fmap (fn1 . fn2). Haskell notes function composition using a single dot (.) instead of ∘ as in math books. Hence: total = sum (map (sum . square) [1..64]). And as explained in the answers, in that specific context, the rightmost `sum` function happens to behave exactly like `Maybe.fromJust`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing worth internalising; when you map a function over a list<sup>1</sup>, the result is **always** going to be a list with the same number of elements. The function will be applied to each element of the list individually; it cannot combine them into a single summary value. That's just not what `fmap` does.

So with that principle in mind, we know that `fmap sum squares` (where `squares = map square [1..64]`) cannot possibly result in the sum of `squares`. It's going to be `[ sum (square 1), sum (square 2), ... , sum (square 64) ]`. We will then need to apply `sum` again to that whole list, if we want to actually add them up.

That just leaves an explanation for what `sum (square 1)` etc is actually doing (i.e. what `sum` does when applied to `Maybe` values). The proper type for `sum` is `sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a`. `Foldable` is basically the type-class of structures that you can scan for 0 or more elements in order (essentially: those you can convert to a list). All `sum` does is add up the elements that are there, however many there are (and use `0` as a "starting value" in case there are no elements). `Maybe` has a `Foldable` instance; it always has 0 or 1 elements, and `sum` can add those up just as well as it can add up lists that happen to have only 0 or 1 elements.

Of course the *effect* of summing zero-or-one numbers is just that the result is 0 if there were zero inputs and equal the input number if there was one. `+` never actually gets called for this "sum", which makes it feel a little pointless. But `sum` didn't know that; it works for any `Foldable`, regardless of how many elements they contain. And `Maybe` didn't know that it would end up being used to "sum without actually adding"; it just implemented `Foldable` so that any other function that wants to scan a variable number of elements out of a structure can scan `Maybe`s.

If you think it's silly, just don't use `sum` for that job; use `fromMaybe 0` instead.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can generalise this to other functors beyond lists; when you `fmap` a function over a data structure, the result will have exactly the same structure as the input. Only the "leaf nodes" will be different.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I was indeed hung up because of my mental association of sum with adding, and failed to consider how fmap can't return a different data structure than what I pass to it. The suggestion to use `fromMaybe` instead is very helpful to avoid this confusion for me.

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at the type of `sum`:

```
sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a
```

Often, for a beginner, this is simplified by assuming that `t ~ []`, so that we instead use `sum` as

```
sum :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

If we try to use `sum` at this type in your example, we will get a type error, because you have a list of Maybe numbers, not a list of numbers. Instead you write `fmap sum [Just 1]`, specializing `sum` and `fmap` to:

```
sum :: Maybe Integer -> Integer
fmap :: (Maybe Integer -> Integer) -> [Maybe Integer] -> [Integer]
```

So the question isn't really "why isn't `sum` adding things", so much as "how can `sum` have a meaningful definition when given a single Maybe Integer?"

One way to answer that question, if you're not familiar with how to interpret `sum` as working on `Foldable` or how `Maybe` is foldable, is to just try implementing it yourself. There's really only one reasonable implementation:

```
sum :: Maybe Integer -> Integer
sum Nothing = 0
sum (Just x) = x
```

Right? Someone asked you "what's the total of the numbers in here", and then gave you either zero or one number. Pretty easy to add up. That's exactly how `sum` works for Maybe, except that it goes through Foldable instead of being specialized to Maybe.

After this, of course it's easy: you've turned your `[Maybe Integer]` into an `[Integer]`, and of course `sum`ming that gets you the sum of the non-`Nothing` entries.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at an example.

```
map square [0..2] = [Nothing, Just 1, Just 2]
fmap sum (map square [0..2]) = [sum Nothing, sum (Just 1), sum (Just 2)]
```

Since `Maybe` is a `Foldable` container, it makes sense to calculate the sum of its elements:

```
sum Nothing = 0
sum (Just a) = a
```

So

```
fmap sum (map square [0..2]) = [0, 1, 2]
```

Now I don't know what you were actually hoping to do with the `Maybe`s, but this is why you got what you got.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `fmap` in

```
total = sum (fmap sum (map square [1..64]))
```

is just `map`:

```
total = sum ( map sum (map square [1..64]))
```

and the `map`s compose by composing their mapping functions,

```
total = sum ( map (sum . square)  [1..64] )
```

and a `map` applies its function to each element of the list,

```
total = sum [sum (square x) | x <- [1..64] ]
```

while a composed function finds its result in steps,

```
total = sum [sum y    | x <- [1..64], y      <- [square x] ]
```

whereas the inner `sum` is working with the result of `square`, namely, a `Maybe` number,

```
total = sum [    n    | x <- [1..64], Just n <- [square x] ]
      = sum [    n    | x <- [1..64], Just n <- list (square x) ]
                                          where list y = [y]
```

and turning `sum y` into just `n` works because `sum` finds a sum and `0` is its identity, so adding a `0` is the same as not adding anything at all. Meaning, the `Just n` pattern match *fails* when `square` produces a `Nothing` (which in our case is *never*, but never mind that) so *that*  *`x`* which causes it is *skipped over*.

```
total = sum [    n    | x <- [1..64], n <- maybeToList (square x) ]
      = sum [    n    | x <- [1..64], n <- case (square x) of
                                                    Just n -> [n]
                                                    Nothing -> [] ]
```

But again, we know that this never happens, and all this repackaging of the same number is all for naught, so in the end your code is equivalent to

```
total = sum [    n    | x <- [1..64], Just n <- [Just (2^(x-1))] ]
      = sum [    n    | x <- [1..64],      n <- [      2^(x-1) ] ]
      = sum [ 2^(x-1) | x <- [1..64] ]
```

just as you intended.

Seeing is better than believing (well, remembering / imagining, which is needed when using higher order functions ... unless of course one has an eidetic memory so for them believing *is* seeing). It might even give us new ideas for further code simplification, some transformations, and, eventually, maybe even some computational optimizations:

```
total = sum    [ 2^x | x <- [0..63] ]
      = sum    [ product (replicate x 2) | x <- [0..63] ]
      = sum $  [ product (replicate 0 2) ] 
            ++ [ product (replicate x 2) | x <- [1..63] ]
      = sum $  [ product [] ] 
            ++ [ 2 * product (replicate (x-1) 2) | x <- [1..63] ]
      = sum $  [ 1 ] 
            ++ [ 2 * product (replicate x     2) | x <- [0..62] ]
      = sum [1] + sum ( [2*n0] ++
               [ 2 * product (replicate x     2) | x <- [1..62] ] )
           where { n0=1 }
      = n0 + sum [n1] + sum( [2*n1] ++
               [ 2 * product (replicate x     2) | x <- [2..62] ] )
           where { n0=1 ; n1=2*n0 }
      = n0 + n1 + n2 + sum( [2*n2] ++
               [ 2 * product (replicate x     2) | x <- [3..62] ] )
           where { n0=1 ; n1=2*n0 ; n2=2*n1 }
      = ....
      = sum . take 64 $ iterate (2*) 1
```

And there they are again, the 64 squares of the chess board, and the first single grain of rice, which is doubled, and doubled again, as we ago along the squares.